# Rectangle around selected ListView item

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to draw a rectangle around the selected item in a ListView, due to reading somewhere that Microsoft recommends against changing the 'highlighted colour' of said item. However, I'm using the selectedIndexChanged event and when the actual listviewitem is drawn my rectangle disappears. An educated guess would suggest my rectangle is either behind it or has being cleared when it has being redrawn? So my question is, when would be the best time to actually draw the rectangle as so it is visible? my code so far can be seen below:

```
 void lvMain_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lvMain.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            if (lastSelectedItem == null) // First time called
            {
                lastSelectedItem = (sender as System.Windows.Forms.ListView).SelectedItems[0];
                DrawHighlightRectanlge(lastSelectedItem);
            }
            else
            {
                // TODO: Remove previous highlight
                lastSelectedItem = (sender as System.Windows.Forms.ListView).SelectedItems[0];
                DrawHighlightRectanlge(lastSelectedItem);
            }
        }
    }

    internal void DrawHighlightRectanlge(System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem item)
    {
        using (Graphics g = item.ListView.CreateGraphics())
        {                
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red), new Rectangle(item.Position.X, item.Position.Y, item.Bounds.Width, item.Bounds.Height));
        }
    }
```

TIA

Comment: Yes it is overpainted in the `DrawItem` event. Which is where you need to go and add your Rectangle drawing code. note that you'll need to take carte of all drawing now; but most of the hard stuff can be done by calling the functions in the `e` parameter.. - Which view mode do you use?

Comment: I'm using the 'Details' view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic version for an owner-drawn `ListView`. Set the `OwnerDraw` property to true and code the `DrawItem` event, maybe like this:

```
private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawText();

    if (e.Item.Selected)
    {
        Rectangle R = e.Bounds;  
        R.Inflate(-1, -1);
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1.5f))
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, R);
    }
}
```

I make the rectangle a little smaller for it to work in `Details View`, but you should play around to make it suit your needs and fancy..!

Note: If you have ColumnHeaders you also need to code the `DrawColumnHeader` event, in its simplest form like this:

```
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, 
                                        DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}
```

And if you have SubItems you need to have a `DrawSubItem` event, again at least like this:

```
private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}
```

Obviously you need to write more code to this event, if you want your rectangle to be drawn here as well. But the default function of `DrawBackground` and `DrawText` are available here as well.